# Storing 2-dimensional ints as Readonly/const in separate class whilst keeping non-exposed

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

This is my first question after having used this place as my "go to" for a general opinion on what works/doesn't/why and the such.  So let's try this out...

With my limited experience I've been trying to get my head round the better ways of creating fixed data fields that I can refer back to throughout my program - things like end-user-viewable strings that I show repeatedly and other parameters that I'd like to keep constant and safe from change.  I've kept my reused data in separate static classes and put my strings in `private static readonly` arrays that I expose through the use of wrapping in private `ILists` that have public getters that return the single string I'm after.  Hopefully I've not abused terminology so far!
What I've done so far:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static partial class Tables
    {
          private static readonly string[] _Messages =
                  {
                      "One",
                      "Two"
                  };

          private static readonly IList<string> MessagesReadOnly = Array.AsReadOnly(_Messages);
          public static IList<string> Messages { get { return MessagesReadOnly; } }
    }
}
```

That much I understand but now I've got a 2 dimensional table of data (`int`) that I need to store in a similarly non-exposed manner that I can access.
This data is going into its own class as now I'm dealing with a separate real-world data type.
Real-world scenario - I've got different fuels with their associated combustion constants that I'll need to access to perform combustion analysis using data that I get from a gas analyser.  So I want to keep these arrays/lists separate with all their methods but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

If I do like I did before and go via the route of array (but 2D this time) then I run into the issue that it seems (according to info on MSDN) that `Array.AsReadOnly(myArray)` only works for one-dimensional arrays.  I'm not savvy enough to know exactly how to write my own to work around this (assuming that's a simple enough task).  So then if I go to trying to use **jagged** arrays, as that seems to be the other viable route I've found, I get stuck trying to figure out how and where to create the initial jagged array (constructor or as class method) and then what about where to initialise the array within that?

If I didn't need to protect the array then I can put it all in the constructor and that might be ok (as far as I can tell so far) but I have to keep it non-exposed.  The first way I understood how that programatically fit within a class but trying to use jagged arrays non-exposed has got me all muddled up.  All the examples I see on the web seem to create them and initialise within `main` which is fine (although exposed) but as I'm putting this elsewhere how can I make it available to anything that might need the data whilst not exposing them?

Hopefully you understand why I feel like I'm going in circles, maybe the answer is really simple and I'm missing the obvious but until I see someone else do similar I can't figure it out, and I haven't been able to find anything close enough to give me the clues.  If there already exists a similar post on SO please point me in that direction.  Like I've said, I've scoured both MSDN, SO and wandered the web in search of breadcrumbs.

Let me know if you need more info about what I've been trying and thanks for reading.

I've just been adding tags to this question and seen that there's an Array tag so I'm off to see if I can narrow things down some more there.  Not sure if I should add that tag too, I could add Lists also...?

Comment: tl;dr... is there a question there?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of data you could be storing inside assembly resources.

Comment: @Gabe: Sorry you thought this was too long - just being specific and telling what I've done so far. And yes there was a question in there somewhere

Comment: So those 8 paragraphs are all just to ask "How do I create an immutable 2D array"?

Comment: Yes... if I knew all I had to do was ask "How do I create an immutable 2D array?" then I would have asked just that.  There are plenty of questions on SO that are much longer than this - do you make a point to "tl dr" them also?  Everyone has to start somewhere and right now I don't always know how to ask in 10 words or less what I want, or how much info I should give or not give in my questions.  That's the problem when you're learning something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This data is going into its own class as now I'm dealing with a separate real-world data t

If you're going to be storing this in a custom class, you could just write a [custom read-only indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) for that class.

This would look something like:

```
private YourType[,] internalArray; // Create and set this up in constructor or elsewhere...


public YourType this[int row, int column]
{
     get 
     {
          return internalArray[row,column];
     }
{
```

Comment: The problem is that in this way he loses the enumerability of the array and the Length property.

Comment: @xanatos: I don't think so.. `internalArray` is a jagged array so we have those properties and we can even define few public properties for that purpose.

Comment: @xanatos: Not if his class implements `IEnumerable<YourClass>` and/or `ICollection<YourClass>` - its easy enough to re-expose that information as needed.

Comment: Yeah... THIS is becoming more complete... you could/should add an IList<YourClass>

Comment: @xanatos: I actually would recommend against implementing `IList<YourClass>`, as he specifically does not want much of the IList behavior, such as .Add/.Remove/etc.  It's better to expose the minimum requirements for interfaces...

Comment: @Reed THAT is ICollection. IList adds the [] operator and Insert/Remove.

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, but IList also includes ICollection - and [] is a useless operator here, since he's using a 2 parameter indexer (IList will force him to also include a single parameter indexer).

Comment: Just logged in a moment ago thinking I'd had no emails telling me someone had posted something in response to my question but was pleasantly surprised - wasn't actually thinking I'd see anything yet so thanks everyone - I'll try these out.This looks promising... I shall try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Reed:  Worked perfectly thanks. Looked up on the subject & found that if I had others that I'd want to index in the same class I can't do it unless the indexer args are different (because of `this`). General solution appears to be turn the 2nd indexer into a method. Wandering if you know of any way to distinguish 2 indexers fetching both `int row, int col` but from different arrays? And is there any real difference to the indexer and a method like `public int GetX(int row, int col) { return X[row, col]; }`?

Comment: @MooMoo: THere really are no differences between a method and an indexer, other than syntax.  That being said - take care here.  Multiple indexes of the same type into a single class screams of a need for redesign or refactoring - it sounds like this class is trying to do too much.  Consider refactoring into separate classes, exposed via a single property, or something similar, to keep this class from becoming huge.  Remember, each class should have a single responsibility...

Comment: @Reed: Yup, will do.  I really just want this to store my fuel constants and that's it, but was curious about the "what if...".  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your jagged array in the static constructor of your static class.

So

```
public static readonly IList<IList<int>> array;

static Tables() {
    // Init array
    // Make it read only
    List<IList<int>> ar1 = new List<IList<int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        List<int> ar2 = new List<int>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            ar2.Add(j);
        }
        ar1.Add(ar2.AsReadOnly());
    }

    array = ar1.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a `List<List<Yourcustom_class>>` for this purpose and define a public readonly property that has only a getter for retrieving data.