# How can I get the equivalent of C++'s "const" in C#?

Tags: c#

In C++, if I want an object to be initialized at compile time and never change thereafter, I simply add the prefix `const`.

In C#, I write

```
    // file extensions of interest
    private const List<string> _ExtensionsOfInterest = new List<string>()
    {
        ".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".png", ".jpg"
    };
```

and get the error

> A const field of a reference type other than string can only be
>   initialized with null

Then I research the error on Stack Overflow and the proposed "solution" is to use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. [A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952990/a-const-field-of-a-reference-type-other-than-string-can-only-be-initialized-with)

But that doesn't really give me the behavior I want, because

```
    // file extensions of interest
    private static ReadOnlyCollection<string> _ExtensionsOfInterest = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>()
    {
        ".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".png", ".jpg"
    };
```

can still be ***reassigned***.

So how do I do what I'm trying to do?

(It's amazing how C# has every language feature imgaginable, except the ones I want)

Comment: `private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string>`

Comment: You found the answer and miss important point of it (it contains the hint). Learning is hard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use the `readonly` modifier

```
private readonly static ReadOnlyCollection<string> _ExtensionsOfInterest = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>()
{
    ".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".png", ".jpg"
};
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed that the ReadOnlyCollection type doesnt allow an empty constructor or supplying of the list in the brackets. You must supply the list in the constructor.

So really you can just write it as a normal list which is readonly.

```
private readonly static List<string> _ExtensionsOfInterestList = new List<string>()
{
    ".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".png", ".jpg"
};
```

or if you really want to use the ReadOnlyCollection you need to supply the above normal list in the constructor.

```
private readonly static ReadOnlyCollection<string> _ExtensionsOfInterest = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_ExtensionsOfInterestList);
```